# PushSharp events not firing for WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, notifications, pushsharp

I have [PushSharp](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp) successfully sending push notifications to Android, BB10, and iOS devices.  I want to being sending notifications to WP8+ devices but it seems that nothing I do successfully registers the WindowsPhoneService.

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
PushBroker push = new PushBroker();
push.OnNotificationSent += NotificationSent;
push.OnChannelException += ChannelException;
push.OnServiceException += ServiceException;
push.OnNotificationFailed += NotificationFailed;
push.OnDeviceSubscriptionExpired += DeviceSubscriptionExpired;
push.OnDeviceSubscriptionChanged += DeviceSubscriptionChanged;
push.OnChannelCreated += ChannelCreated;
push.OnChannelDestroyed += ChannelDestroyed;

push.RegisterWindowsPhoneService();

WindowsPhoneToastNotification windowsPhoneToastNotification = new    WindowsPhoneToastNotification()
    .ForEndpointUri(new Uri([[Device Uri]]))
    .ForOSVersion(WindowsPhoneDeviceOSVersion.Eight)
    .WithBatchingInterval(BatchingInterval.Immediate)
    .WithNavigatePath("/MainPage.xaml")
    .WithText1("Test 1")
    .WithText2("Test 2")
;

push.StopAllServices();
```

Everything is pretty straightforward but notifications are not sent and no events get fired. Nothing.  I can hit breakpoints all the way to "push.StopAllServices();" but not any breakpoints in any of the PushSharp-related events.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of PushSharp, there is a parameter to pass to the "StopAllService" for waiting the queue sended before stop :

//
push.StopAllServices(true);

This will force the pushchannel to send the notifications in the queue.